# Android Library: run tests from command line

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Android library doesn't have **gradlew** file, so how can I run tests from a command line? I need it to integrate my android library with CI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more important question is: Is it a gradle project (is there a `build.gradle`)?

`gradlew` is just a script file that downloads and executes gradle. You can simple [download gradle](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) yourself and execute it if it is a gradle project.

Alternatively you can simply copy a working `gradlew` from a similar project into this project. The file is usually identical in all projects.

Comment: yes, it's a gradle project, it has build.gradle, but by default doesn't have gradlew file